# PHP UPDATE prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, prepared-statement

I'm trying to learn the proper way to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections etc.

When I execute the script I get a message from my script saying 0 Rows Inserted, I expect this to say 1 Rows Inserted and of course update the table. I'm not entirely sure on my prepared statement, as I've done some research and I mean it varies from example to example.

When I'm updating my table do I need to declare all the fields or is it ok to just update one field??

Any information would be very helpful.

index.php

```
<div id="status"></div>

    <div id="maincontent">
    <?php //get data from database.
        require("classes/class.Scripts.inc");
        $insert = new Scripts();
        $insert->read();
        $insert->update();?>

       <form action="index2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="update" id="update">
              <textarea name="content" id="content" class="detail" spellcheck="true" placeholder="Insert article here"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="update" name="update" value="update" />
    </div>
```

classes/class.Scripts.inc

```
public function update() {
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE datadump SET content=? WHERE id=?");
        $id = 1;
        /* Bind our params */                           
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $id, $content);
        /* Set our params */
        $content = isset($_POST['content']) ? $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['content']) : '';

        /* Execute the prepared Statement */
        $stmt->execute();
        printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

    }                   
}
```

Comment: Did you try it to see what happens?

Comment: real_escape_string() is not necessary for prepared statements

Comment: In your SQL, the first parameter is content and the second is ID. When you call bind_param, you've reversed the order - try swapping the order around in bind_param

Comment: @PatrickKostjens I did try this and it doesn't effect the table at all

Comment: Verify that you not updating with same content, and from an existing id. Otherwise, effectively MySQL have right : nothing to update.

Comment: @gutigrewal, then mention that in your question along with what you did expect to happen.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE datadump SET content=? WHERE id=?");
/* BK: always check whether the prepare() succeeded */
if ($stmt === false) {
  trigger_error($this->mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);
  return;
}
$id = 1;
/* Bind our params */
/* BK: variables must be bound in the same order as the params in your SQL.
 * Some people prefer PDO because it supports named parameter. */
$stmt->bind_param('si', $content, $id);

/* Set our params */
/* BK: No need to use escaping when using parameters, in fact, you must not, 
 * because you'll get literal '\' characters in your content. */
$content = $_POST['content'] ?: '';

/* Execute the prepared Statement */
$status = $stmt->execute();
/* BK: always check whether the execute() succeeded */
if ($status === false) {
  trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
```

Re your questions:

> I get a message from my script saying 0 Rows Inserted

This is because you reversed the order of parameters when you bound them.  So you're searching the id column for the numeric value of your $content, which is probably interpreted as 0.  So the UPDATE's WHERE clause matches zero rows.

> do I need to declare all the fields or is it ok to just update one field??

It's okay to set just one column in an UPDATE statement.  Other columns will not be changed.

Comment: What is the first argument on line 10 for?

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson: one letter for each parameter. 's' for string, 'i' for integer, etc. Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: `@BillKarwin` For me `$status variable` is showing `integer` value . I used `echo $status` and the output is `1`.

Comment: @NimmagaddaGowtham, when you echo a `true` value, PHP prints `1`.

Comment: how does `$stmt->bind_param('si', $content, $id)` work before you declare the value of `$content`?

Comment: @stib, it binds to the variables by reference. It does not copy their value at the time you bind to them. Then you can modify the value, and `execute()` sends the value to MySQL at that time. It sends whatever the current value of the variable is at the time you `execute()`. This means you can bind variables to a prepared statement and then run a loop, modifying the values and using `execute()` many times inside the loop. No need to re-bind the variables during every loop iteration in that case.

Answer (score 13):

In fact, prepared statements are not that complex as it's shown in the other answer. Quite contrary, a prepared statement is the most simple and tidy way to execute a query. Take, for example, your case. You need only three lines of code!

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE datadump SET content=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('si', $content, $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

1. Prepare your query with placeholders
2. Then bind variables (a hint: you can safely use "s" for any variable)
3. And then execute the query.

As simple as 1-2-3!

Note that checking every function's result manually is just insane, it would only bloat your code without any benefit. Instead you should [configure mysqli to report errors automatically](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting) once for all. To do so, add the following line before `mysqli_connect()`/`new mysqli`:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

the result will be pretty much the same as with trigger_error but without an single extra line of code! As you can see, the code could be very simple and concise, if used properly.

Answer (score -1):

I want to clean up Bill Karwin's awesome code

```
$stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE datadump SET content=? WHERE id=?") or die ($this->mysqli->error);

$id = 1;

// Bind our params
// BK: variables must be bound in the same order as the params in your SQL.
// Some people prefer PDO because it supports named parameter.
$stmt->bind_param('si', $content, $id) or die ($stmt->error);

// Set our params
// BK: No need to use escaping when using parameters, in fact, you must not, 
// because you'll get literal '\' characters in your content. */
$content = (string)$_POST['content'] ?: '';

/* Execute the prepared Statement */
$status = $stmt->execute() or die ($stmt->error);


printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
```

I recommend using "or die" instead of if clause
I recommend forcing a variable type to take values:

```
// If id brings value: '12abc', PHP automatically stops it at 12
$id = (int)$_ POST ["id"];
```

Comment: [I don't recommend using "or die"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15318368/mysqli-or-die-does-it-have-to-die)

Comment: You haven't cleaned up the code, instead you made it worse and you introduced new vulnerabilities. See YCS's answer how to do it properly.