# MYSQL: Why this update query won't work?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying this sql query, and it won't work:

```
<form name="modificarUsuario" action="" method="POST">
<h2>Modificación de Datos Personales</h2>
Username: <input type="text" name="username" />  
Nombre Completo: <input type="text" name="nombre" />  
Email: <input type="text" name="email" />  
Clave: <input type="text" name="pass" />  
<input type="submit" class="button" name="modificarDatos" value="Modificar datos">
<br>
</form>

$usuario = $_POST['username'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$clave = $_POST['pass'];
$uid = 1;
$consulta = mysqli_prepare($conectar,
                "UPDATE usuario 
                 SET username = ?, pass = ?, name = ?, email = ?) 
                 WHERE uid = '".$uid."'
                ");
if ($consulta) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $consulta, 'ssss', $usuario, $clave, $nombre, $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta);
    echo 'Se guardaron los cambios';
}
else {echo 'Hubo un error! El cambio no se guardó!';}
mysqli_stmt_close($consulta); //here's line 52
```

The error is:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given in ...

The database has an "usuario" table, with an "uid" field, which is an integer.
All fields are correctly spelled and in the right order:
uid, username, pass, name, email

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485039/mysql-insert-where-query) and [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316501/php-update-prepared-statement), and they both have interesting information about what could have been wrong. But I've checked and everything seems ok.

Comment: Why are you using bound parameters for `username`, `pass`, `name` and `email`, but string substitution for `uid`?

Comment: I've harcoded it. There's only one user in the database, the admin. Thought it was easier to test that the code worked as expected.

Comment: And can you show us a small, complete example that demonstrates the problem? I can't quite see from the code you've posted how you'd have an error preparing the statement—as seems to be happening—but not get your error message out. (Also: it may help if you output `$mysqli->error` if the prepare fails.) Leaving things out of your code, like the php tags, may not be helping us understand the whole situation. It's often a hint that other important things are missing.

Comment: @Rosamunda You really should bind *all* parameters just to be on the safe side. This is how you create nasty bugs by mistake: Step one is always innocent enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a spurious close paren character in your SQL text (the string containing the UPDATE statement). And that's a MySQL syntax violation.

```
, email = ?) 
           ^
```

If the `mysqli_prepare` fails (i.e. returns FALSE), you should retrieve the error message with `mysqli_error($connectar)`, that would let you see the syntax error.

```
 else {
    echo 'Hubo un error! El cambio no se guardó!';
    echo mysqli_error($conectar);
 }
```

The `mysqli_stmt_close` only works if there's a valid statement handle, so that call should be moved up into the "then" block, so it only gets executed when the prepare returned a statement handle.

Comment: You were correct! The issue was that ) that didn't belonged! THANKS!!

Comment: @Rosamunda: At the risk of being redundant, I want to re-emphasize... use **`mysqli_error`** to retrieve the MySQL error. That error would have indicated a MySQL syntax problem, narrowing down where the actual problem was.

Answer (score 0):

from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php):

> mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.

When your prepare statement fails, it will return a boolean, meaning that `$consulta` will not be a statement but a boolean. booleans can't be closed, and `mysqli_stmt_close` wants a statement. So if you pass your failed prepared statement to `mysqli_stmt_close`, you get the error you posted.

so put your close only if it succeeded

```
if ($consulta) {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $consulta, 'ssss', $usuario, $clave, $nombre, $email);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta);
    echo 'Se guardaron los cambios';
    mysqli_stmt_close($consulta);
}
else {echo 'Hubo un error! El cambio no se guardó!';}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it fails, but why? The same statement I've tested it in other place and it worked just fine. I thought that it could be because some silly *grammar* error in my code...

Comment: `$conectar` is not set in the code you posted. That could be the issue.

Comment: the error in your question is related to the `mysql_stmt_close`, not the prepare. if the prepare fails, that is another question @Rosamunda

Comment: $conectar is included, in a different file, used in several other places (that's why I know that it works). 
If I put mysqli_stmt_close() only when it succeeds, tehre's no error, but it won't update either.

Comment: @Rosamunda then why show the error of the `mysql_stmt_close` if it's about the `mysqli_prepare` that you want to ask?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier that's only partly correct, `mysql_stmt_close` fails because the prepare fails (and there's no check to see if the prepare was successful), so I would say a proper solution not only adds error handling but also fixes the prepare issue.

Comment: @Arjan yes, the `mysql_stmt_close` fails because the prepare fails, that's exactly what I'm saying...