# Difference between $con->prepare versus $con->sqli->prepare

Tags: php

I was always taught and used $con->prepare for prepared statements. However, this article two answers posted people where using [$con->sqli->prepare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316501/php-update-prepared-statement). I also saw a few others using it in other articles.

Is this something to be concerned with?
What is the difference?

Comment: They've written their own class that wraps PDO or mysqli, and `$this->con` contains the connection object.

Comment: it should be `$this->con`, not `$this->$con`. You don't put a `$` before the property name (unless you're using a variable property).

Comment: This is object orienteted language. Please refere here: https://secure.php.net/language.oop5

Comment: This is not the same as the “ducplicated” article. The question is about the extra ->sqli arrow not $this (which in this case is just thnot connection. Thr guy below posted the correct answer. I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually some people make database connection class with constructor of connection. It means that when you initialize the object of that class, the constructor is executed automatically.
For example *here is Database class*

```
<?php

class db
{
    public $conn;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","prepared");//A constructor is a function that is executed after the object has been initialized (its memory allocated, instance properties copied etc.). Its purpose is to put the object in a valid state.
        if($this->conn)
        {
            echo "";
        }
        else{
            echo $this->conn->error;
        }
    }
}
$db = new db();

?>
```

**Child class**

```
include("db.php");

 class childclass extends db
{




public function database_query()//here you don't need to put $conn in parameters
 {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
    $result = $this->conn->query($sql);//Here you can see how we can call conn from db class
    print_r($result);





 }
}
```

I hope you got my point.

Comment: FWIW, *is* `interactions` *a* `db`? Could you substitute an instance of `interactions` anytime you'd use a `db`? Probably not.

Comment: @deceze Sorry! I was in hurry. I just copy pasted.

Comment: Thanks. This post is the correct answer (not the guy above who said this was a duplicate).

Comment: I glad I helped you