# How to insert values for the current session user using $stmt = $connect->prepare

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is my current code for adding some additional information to a database table named `klantinfo`. This information is added after the user is logged in. At the login, the given username gets inserted into the `login` table, but also into the `klantinfo` table. This way I can compare the username in the database with the username in the session, so I can display the correct data for the logged in user.

```
if (!$error) {
    
    
    $stmt = $connect->prepare("
        INSERT INTO klantinfo (voornaam, achternaam, telefoonnummer, straat, straatnummer, stad, postcode) 
        VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $voornaam, $achternaam, $telnr, $straat, $straatnummer, $stad, $postcode);
    
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        
        $success_message = "De registratie is gelukt. U kunt nu inloggen.";
        
    } else {
        
        $error_message = "Error. Probeer het later opnieuw.";
        
    }
}
```

However, this just inserts the values into a new row in the database table. I want it to specifically insert the values into the already existing row of the user (the one with the username already in it) thats currently in the session.

I already tried other queries, with no luck.

For example, I tried adding this to the query:

`WHERE username_info='$user'`

Nothing works!

Comment: Refer back to your introductory SQL tutorials. If you want to change an existing row, you just use an `UPDATE` query, not an `INSERT`

Comment: Already tried that. Didnt work either.

Comment: Didn't work how, specifically? Show what you tried and explain what error or problems you had. You definitely need an `UPDATE` if you want to change a row. If you made a mistake when writing your `UPDATE` statement, that's a different issue, and to fix it we need to see the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an `UPDATE` statement instead of an `INSERT` statement. `UPDATE` changes the values in the database without inserting a new row whereas `INSERT` adds another row to the database. You can refer here:
[UPDATE(docs)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/update_statement.htm)

[INSERT(docs)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm)

[INSERT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

[UPDATE](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_update.asp)

Comment: Thanks! Now i just dont get how to use that with $stmt = $connect -> prepare and $stmt->bind_param

Comment: Here's an example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316501/php-update-prepared-statement)

Comment: Thanks! This helped me solve it. I solved it in a terribly ineffecient way, but it works.